# SSRS foreach loop based on the ids of a query

Tags: reporting-services

I'm very new with SSRS and currently struggling with what I want to achieve.
Imagine having a query that returns these data:

| UserId | From | To | Value | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-1 | 2021-10-31 | 10 | Name1 |
| 1 | 2021-11-1 | 2021-11-30 | 20 | Name1 |
| 2 | 2021-10-1 | 2021-10-31 | 100 | Name2 |
| 2 | 2021-11-1 | 2021-11-30 | 200 | Name2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

In my SSRS report I king of want a foreach-Loop so that every user gets his own section based on the UserId like:

Name: Name1

| From | To | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-1 | 2021-10-31 | 10 |
| 2021-11-1 | 2021-11-30 | 20 |

Name: Name2

| From | To | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-1 | 2021-10-31 | 100 |
| 2021-11-1 | 2021-11-30 | 200 |

...

How is this possible to achieve?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding a grouping to the same table may solve your issue, you may want a table or multiple objects to repeat for individual groups.

In this case, you may want to use a LIST object to group your data and then put your table (and any other objects you may want), inside a single (large) cell of the LIST.

There is a table of Regions, but it needs repeat it for a higher group - COUNTRY.

[image]

Add a LIST and group by the COUNTRY field. Make the single cell the same size as the other table. Put the Region table inside the single cell of the COUNTRY List. For you scenario, you would use the UserID.

[image]

The list repeats for each Country. For you table, it would repeat for each user.

A row (inside group) can be added so a separate header can be created for each User so you can add their ID, name and whatever else is needed on the report.

Answer (score 1):

Add a row group with a group header that groups by UserID.

[image]

In the rowgroup header you can put the Users name and ID etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you want to seperate out each set of rows by the value in the `UserId` field, you just need to add a table to your report that has a `group` based on the `UserId` field.

If you do that, the table will group together all the rows for each unique `UserId` and also allow you to add subtotals etc

Comment: Thats close but not exactly what I need if I understood it correclty. This would give me one grouped table right? 
I want a seperate table for each UserId so so that I can additional textfields like the name above each table

Comment: @xeraphim  The group exists *within* the table, so you can add items both in and outside of any grouping.  This means you can add column headers that either repeat with each group or simply sit at the top of the table itself.  If you want to display the data as if it is in its own table, just add a couple table rows inside the group, one at the top above your actual data and one at the bottom, that are formatted to look like the top and bottom of a table.  These will then repeat with each group of data giving the impression of multiple tables.